# How to extract day, month and year (dd-MM-yyyy) from Date (2018-09-28 09:42:00 +0000 ) without time in Date format - iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I want to get 2018-09-28 from 2018-09-28 09:42:00 +0000 in Date format. I 
 can extract the same in string format but I want to get this in Date format. Here is my sample code.

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (TimeInterval(timer/1000)))
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let myDate = df.string(from: date)
let updateDate = df.date(from: myDate)
```

//date - 2018-09-28
//updateDate - 2018-09-28 09:42:00 +0000

Comment: @Sh_Khan I want to get dd-MM-yyyy in Date format not in string

Comment: create data with zero hour,minute,seconds components and set other components from the date you have

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: @Carpsen90 Added my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get your date string prefix 11 and insert noon time when parsing your string:

```
let str = "2018-09-28 09:42:00 +0000"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
```

---

```
if let date = df.date(from: str.prefix(11) + "12:00") {
    print(date.description(with: .current))
}

// Friday, September 28, 2018 at 12:00:00 PM Brasilia Standard Time
```